# JS classes how do i know how to use self or this

Tags: javascript

I have a class object that handles some movement for an object. In the mouseMove all the variables need to be a `self` even the static values like `paddleWidth` but in the movement function the `this` key word worked for the static values of `paddleWidth`. Could someone help me understand how to know when self should be used instead of this?

```
export class Paddle {
constructor (world) {
    var self = this;
    this.canvas = world.canvas;
    this.ctx = world.ctx;
    this.paddleHeight = 10;
    this.paddleWidth = 75;
    this.paddleX = (this.canvas.width - this.paddleWidth) / 2; // location
    this.rightPressed = false;
    this.leftPressed = false;
    this.keyDownHandler= function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 39) {
            self.rightPressed = true;
        }
        else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
            self.leftPressed = true;

        }
    };

    this.keyDown = document.addEventListener("keydown", this.keyDownHandler, false);

    this.keyUpHandler= function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 39) {
            self.rightPressed = false;
        }
        else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
            self.leftPressed = false;

        }
    };

    this.keyUp = document.addEventListener("keyup", this.keyUpHandler, false);

    this.mouseMoveHandler = function(e) {
        console.log('mouseMove', this.paddleX)
        var relativeX = e.clientX - self.canvas.offsetLeft;
        if(relativeX > 0 && relativeX < self.canvas.width){
            self.paddleX = relativeX - self.paddleWidth/2
        }
    };

    this.mouseMove = document.addEventListener("mousemove", this.mouseMoveHandler, false);

    this.movement= function() {
        console.log('movement', this.paddleX)
        if (this.rightPressed && this.paddleX < this.canvas.width - this.paddleWidth) {
            self.paddleX += 7;
        } else if (this.leftPressed && this.paddleX > 0) {
            self.paddleX -= 7;
        }
    };
  }
```

Comment: Use anonymous arrow functions instead and use `this` everywhere, never use `self`. eg `.addEventListener("keydown", () => this.keyDownHandler())`. Also consider using methods in your class instead of assigning them in the constructor

Comment: @CertainPerformance, you can't always avoid the use of `self` though. The `movement` function requires the function to use a `this` relative to the function rather than the class but then `self` is required to access the class properties. I do completely agree that in all cases, where possible, the use of `self` should be avoided.

Comment: @SimonK I don't think it's needed. We don't see where `movement` is invoked, but it's probably meant to be invoked with a context of the instantiated object, in which case using `this` everywhere will work just fine. OP is using both `self` and `this` in the function, but replacing all `self`s with `this` should work. If some function *did* need access to both `this` and another instantiated object, that other object should be passed as a parameter, rather than using `.call` or something to alter the calling context.

Comment: @CertainPerformance thanks for the tip, ill give it a try. do i have to turn my declared functions or key up and down handlers into arrow functions too or just the call backs like your example? `.addEventListener("keydown", () => this.keyDownHandler())`?

Comment: Only the callbacks need it. Still, your other functions *should* be methods on the `Class` rather than being declared in the constructor.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I did it but getting a reference error now. could you check my gist to see what I did wrong? https://gist.github.com/wolffles/0aeb0ba08342917243746b5880731f95

Comment: A reference error where? What's the error?

Comment: oh no its undefined, its cuz i changed something. the code the gist link returns undefined for the variable e.clientX `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.clientX')`

Comment: If you need the event, use it and pass it in the handler arrow function. `(e) => this.keyDownHandler(e)`

Comment: oh wow silly mistake, thanks! its working like a charm! truly appreciate your help! :D